# TestNG Data provider

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng

I'm having trouble using the data provider. The example shown in the TestNG documentation is easy to use. But now I'm trying to use it with a DB to send the .

Here is my data provider:

```
@DataProvider(name = "properties")
    public Object[][] crearDatos() throws Exception {
        List<Map<String, String>> res = sqlAutomationAMFManager.getSqlData(ESqlAutomationAMFFileNames.EMP_LOCAL_CAJA);
        Object[][] aux = new Object[][]{
            for (Map m : res) {
                aux {

                    {
                        m.get("empresa"), m.get("local"), m.get("caja"), m.get("baseDatos")
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        return aux;
```

The res variable is the result of my query which is a list of map of each row, but what I can't figure out is how to set it in aux varible.

This is the example shown on the TestNG Documentation:

```
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
    public Object[][] createData1() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {"Cedric", new Integer(36)},
                {"Anne", new Integer(37)},
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this,

```
Object[][] aux= new Object[][]{res.toArray()};
```

You are trying to iterate over a List object (res) with a Map iterator, which is where it doesn't work for you

Comment: doing that returns me a list of the maps, but what I need is the data inside the map

Answer (score 0):

Or You can use Iterator:

```
    @DataProvider(name = "Data")
    public static Iterator<Object[]> mainProvider(){
        Collection<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        //
        return list.iterator();
    }
```